# Reverse mapping indices in matlab

Tags: matlab, mapping

I have a such index vector which maps the cells. 
For example `(1 -> 310),(2 -> 910),....(1024 -> 67)`

It maps the `8*8 cell`(eg:1st cell) of image to `8*8 cell`(eg:310th cell).

I have `1024 8*8 cells` and I want to reverse this process to get their first indices.

I mean, after this mapping It reorder to the basic order.
(eg: 310th cell comes to 1th and 910th cell comes to 2).

Anyone can help?

yeah sure ,I write my program, for example I have these image blocks for an image.

```
             % dividing of main image to 8*8 blocks:
           U = floor(M1/8);    
           V = floor(M2/8);
          I_div = cell(U,V);
          K = 1; L = 1;
          for u = 1:U
          for v = 1:V
           I_div{u,v} = I2(K:K+7,L:L+7);
          I_div_DCT{u,v} = dct2(I_div{u,v});  %%%  the main blocks 
           L = L + 8;
         end
      K = K + 8;
        L = 1;
   end




       a=reshape(I_div_DCT',[],1)';
       b=cell(1,1024);
       for i=1:1024   
       b(i)=a(index(i));
       end
```

%%%  index is the 1*1024 array, something like this:

```
        %%%  1     2     3       4       5       6       7       8   .... 
         %%% 367  910   274     308     275     429     403      276   ....
```

if the first image block be a(1,1)=[8*8 double]; after implementing b(i)=a(index(i)) it goes to the 367th [8*8]block and for example The 787th [8*8]block comes to the first block,(just a simple mapping).
I want to bring back this blocks into their original indeices after implementing my changes!

Comment: Can you provide a mock example (maybe using `2x2` instead of `8x8`) but with actual before and after numbers so that we can see exactly what you mean? You can edit your original question to add such an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have a forward map

```
fMap = [367, 910, 274, 308, 275, 429, 403, 276, ...
```

Such that index `k` is mapped to `fMap( k )`.

Now you war the "inverse" map that will map `fMap(k)` back to `k`.
Or in other words `k == revMap( fMap( k ) )`.

For simplicity I'll assume `fMap` is a permutation. then

```
revMap( fMap ) = 1:n
```

A small example:

```
>> fMap 
 fMap =
 1     4     5     3     2

>> rMap( fMap ) = 1:5
 rMap =
 1     5     4     2     3
```

Comment: Thank for replying, But it should reorder cell blocks, and when I used your codes, I faced with this expression:                      Error using subsindex
   Function 'subsindex' is not defined
    for values of class 'cell'.

     Error in pak (line 34)
     rMap(b)=1:1024

Comment: @sahandziabari You can probably use `cell2mat` first (And optionally `mat2cell` later)

Comment: @sahandziabari `revMap` should be similar to your `index` array

Comment: Thanks guys(Shai , Dennis)